# Laravel build a queue object using redis cache

Tags: laravel, data-structures, redis

I'm trying to figure something out, i built a logger that keeps track of certain events happening. These happen fairly often (ie 1-500 times a minute).

To optimize this properly, i'm storing to redis and then i have a task that grabs the queue object from redis, clears the cache key and will insert each individual entry into the db.

I have the enqueue happening in the destructor when my logger is done observing the data.

For obvious reasons, i dont want a db write happening every time, so to speed this up i write to redis and then flush to db on a task.

The issue is that my queue implementation is as follows:

1. fetch object with key xyz from redis
2. append new entry to object
3. store object with key xyz in redis

This is inefficient, i would like to be able to just enqueue straight into redis. Redis has a list type built-in which i could use, but laravel redis driver doesn't support it. I tried to figure out a way to send raw commands to redis from laravel, but I can't seem to make it work.

I was thinking of just storing keys into a tag in redis, but i quickly discovered laravel's implementation of tags is not 'proper' and will not allow fetching tagged items without a key, so i can't use tags as a queue and each key an object in it.

If anyone has any idea how i could either talk to redis directly and make use of list, or if there's something i missed, it would really help.

Comment: What do you mean that the Laravel Redis driver doesn't support lists? I'm pretty sure I've used it, and if not, you can always switch Redis driver. Could you please share what you've tried for the list commands?

Comment: Damn, you just made me realize i'm using the facade they provided. Dug through their code and found "getRedis()" which returns an instance of the redis client. 

If i do:         
$redis = Cache::getRedis();
$redis->rpush('test.key', 'data');

It works.

Comment: There is the following hint in the documentation: `Of course, as mentioned above, you may call any of the Redis commands on the Redis facade. Laravel uses magic methods to pass the commands to the Redis server, so pass the arguments the Redis command expects` ([source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redis#interacting-with-redis))

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT*

While the way below does work, there is a more proper way of doing it using a facade for redis as a reply mentioned, more on it here: [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redis#interacting-with-redis)

Okay, if anyone runs into this. I did not see it documented properly anywhere, you need to do the following:

-> get an instance of redis through the Cache facade laravel provides.

```
$redis = Cache::getRedis();
```

-> call redis functions through it.

```
 $redis->rpush('test.key', 'data');
```

I believe you'll want predis as your driver.

If you're building a log driver, you'll want these 2 functions implemented:

```
public function cacheEnqueue($data) : int
{
    $size = $this->_redis->lpush($this->getCacheKey("c_stack_queue"), $data);

    if ($size > 2000)
    {
        //prevent runaway logs
        $this->_redis->ltrim($this->getCacheKey("c_stack_queue"), 0, 2000);
    }


    return $size;
}

/**
 * Fetch items from stack. Multi-thread safe,
 *
 * @param  int $number Fetch last x items.
 * 
 * @return array
 */
public function cachePopMulti(int $number) : array
{
    $data = $this->_redis->lrange($this->getCacheKey("c_stack_queue"), -$number, -1);

    $this->_redis->ltrim($this->getCacheKey("c_stack_queue"), 0, -1 * ($number + 1));

    return $data;
}
```

Of course, write your own key generator getCacheKey()